# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="http://example.com" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="engine" value="v2.5" />
<input type="text" name="verify" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
```

Thanks.

I want to send a POST parameter named submit through forms, how can this be done automatically?

Answer (score 17):

`myForm.submit` is a reference to the text input with `name="submit"`:

```
<input type="text" name="submit" value="Save" />
```

Change the name to something other than "submit".

Answer (score 6):

Since you have an input with the name submit, try to use following line:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit.click();
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackockflow, for an answer please provide more information like why your solution works and what was done wrong. Those answers can be found an google etc. and should be clear for everyone. Thanks for contributing and good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Rename `<input type="text" name="submit" value="Save" />` to something other than `submit`, and it should work.

This is because you can access form values using object notation in Javascript, so by calling `submit()`, you are attempting to execute the `submit` field as a function.

However, your question is how to send a POST parameter named submit.  You might want to take a look at `XMLHttpRequest`, like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://example.com", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("engine=v2.5&verify=2&submit=Save");
```

Answer (score -1):

go to submit button and check if you put id = submit EX:
 if your id was submit you should change it  to other id  that's all

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend editing your answer to explain why this should work. As it sits now, I do not see this as an accurate answer to this question in the least.